# Link2sd pkg error

Tags: root-access, link2sd

I have problem with Link2sd app. When i'm trying to move any app to sd card following error appears. Any ideas how to fix it?

Samsung galaxy J3, 5.1.1 Android

[image]

Answer (score 1):

fixed, solution for the future;

Just open Link2Sd and convert the system app to user app by clicking on the app, then click on the three dots on the top-right corner, then select Converto to user app. After that you have to restart and then you can move to sd, or link if you want to.